# PHP-CLI crash with no logs on the server

Tags: php, logging, debian, crash-dumps

I have got a cron in PHP that crash without any log into the php_errors on a debian. Most of the time (99% of the time), it's work fine and I have no problem with it.
But randomly, it just stop and I have nothing in any log on the server. I have got the issue on 2 different server (with very similar install), always when the load increase.

I installed systemd-coredump on the server because I suspected a segfault into one of php library (the script is complex and make a lot of webservices call) but it didn't log anything on the last crash.
Out of memory are well log into the php_errors, so it doesn't seem to be the problem.

What can I do to gather any logs that can give me a hint on what happen and why my pid just stop ?

Comment: What is the script doing and can you share the code? Depending on what you're doing you could debug and write commands to a log file to see when it crashes.

Comment: When I run into this, I usually start adding logging to my own code. "Starting call to XYZ", "Call to XYZ finished", etc., always with timestamps and sometimes with memory stats, just to see if there's a specific call or time that breaks things

Comment: I cannot share the code, it's a professionnal one. The functionnality of the code is a TMS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_management_system). I will try your hint to log into a textfile, to try to see where i crash, it will be a huge file but it's maybe my last solution :(